# Knockout.js Data-bind into separate variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jsfiddle

I'm new to this and trying to get my head around the following scripts.

http://jsfiddle.net/GSSCD/203/

Here is the HTML

```
<ul data-bind="foreach:servers">
<li> <a href="#" data-bind="text:name,attr:{href: 'http://'+name}">tester</a> <span data-bind="text:status,css:status"></span>

</li>
```

Currently this code along with the javascript from the link retrieves the status of certain servers and outputs it to an html webpage.
Unfortunately for me it outputs all the data in one hit onto the webpage using Data-bind.

Is it at all possible to put each piece of data into its own variable which i can then use as i wish?

So the first server name is put into a variable, then its status is put into a different variable then the second server name is placed into another variable etc.. for all the servers in the list.

I really hope someone can help as i have been staring at this for the last 3 days and not really getting anywhere.

Comment: How exactly you want to use variables? What is wrong with binding in one hit? You have all variables you need in `servers` array of your viewModel. You can access and bind each of your servers individually see [fiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/ft5LhbLy/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy Knockout way of doing it.  You're either going to have to access the url with an ajax request and parse the returned html or maybe manipulate the DOM after it is updated to grab the info you need and populate your variables.